# Pagination function fetching more data than necessary on first trigger

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing pagination in a practice app, basically `scrollViewDidScroll` measures where the user is on the page and when they reach the bottom, I have a `fetchMoreData` function that's triggered. This function uses string interpolation to grab the next page of results from the API.

However I'm running into an issue - when the user reaches the bottom of the page the first time, the page is incremented over and over - my print statement shows that in rapid succession it gets page 2,3,4,5,6, etc endlessly.

This is the pagination code as it stands now:

```
func fetchMoreEvents() {
    page += 1

    let seatGeekApiUrl = URL(string: "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?venue.state=NY&page=\(page)&client_id=MTM5OTE0OTd8MTU0MjU2NTQ4MC4z")!

    fetchData(url: seatGeekApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Welcome>) -> (Void) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.eventData.append(contentsOf: object.events)
            //print("\neventData: \n\n\(self.eventData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\nError decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    print("\nFetching next batch of events: (Page \(page))\n")
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let  height = scrollView.frame.size.height
    let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
    if distanceFromBottom < height {
        fetchMoreEvents()
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong here, and how can I fix this so that it only gets one more page, then waits for the user to reach the bottom again, then one more, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of pieces of information to paginate correctly.  First, as you have already discovered you need a `isLoading` flag to prevent multiple requests while you have a pending request.  Second, you need to have a `pageSize`, which you should be passing into your request.  Third, you need to have a `hasMoreData` flag which is initially true and gets set to false when you get back a result with fewer items than `pageSize` (ie if I ask for 25 items and I get back 5, then it must be that I am on the last page, so `hasMoreData` should be set to false).

Put a guard at the top of your fetch to prevent fetch unless you are not loading and you have more data:

```
guard hasMoreData && isLoading == false else { return }
```